# get id:key from firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I try to delete news using generated form :

```
 <div class="row" *ngFor="let list of newsList">
    <div class="nameNews">
      <h1>{{list.newsName}}</h1>
    </div>
    <div class="shortDescNews">
      <p>{{list.shortDesc}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="descNews">
      <p>{{list.desc}}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="buttonsNews">
      <button type="button" name="button">edytuj</button>
      <button type="button" name="button" (click)="deleteNews()">Usuń</button>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I get the data from function

```
firebase.database().ref('/news').on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
  this.newsList.push(snapshot.val())
})
```

It's the simplest way I think at start...

Now on every genereted row, I have button for delete.

```
deleteNews() {
  var key;
  var ref = firebase.database().ref('/news');
      ref.orderByChild('newsName').equalTo(key).on('child_added', (snapshot) => {
      snapshot.ref.remove()
});
```

}

At the start, I add to key string like new name. But it shouldn't be done like this.
So now I want to delete it via separate key.

How can I get the id for each row and push the id like delete(key) for retrieve in function?

What I want to get :
Each row have separate button delete. For each button id that can be push to function.
When I click in 2nd row button delete, it will delete the object with this id.
The id is auto generated in firebase.

//Solved...
I generated the key like this :

```
var key = firebase.database().ref().push().getKey();
```

When i get the key i just setup that as name, and push it to _key
It solve problem.

Comment: When i try via :
var key = firebase.database().ref('/news').push().getKey();
    console.log(key);

console.log show me everytime other key... No one is the same as the key from /news ...